# angular polyfill problem: IE11 - core-js v3.6.5 method es.string.split.js fails parsing regex /^|\s+/ on split

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, polyfills, core-js

Angular **10**, d3 **5.16.0**, core-js **3.6.5**

The long and short of this is that d3-drag invokes d3-dispatch, which internally calls a method named .parseTypenames.

```
function parseTypenames(typenames, types) {
    return typenames.trim().split(/^|\s+/).map(function (t) {
    var name = "",
        i = t.indexOf(".");
    if (i >= 0) name = t.slice(i + 1), t = t.slice(0, i);
    if (t && !types.hasOwnProperty(t)) throw new Error("unknown type: " + t);
    return {
      type: t,
      name: name
    };
  });
}
```

es.string.split.js is doing something goofy processing the /^|\s+/ regular expression.

```
var foo = 'drag'.split(/^|\s+/) // yields an array = ['d','r','a','g'] when i'm expecting ['drag']
```

Any suggestions on what to do here? Hopefully I don't have a fundamental compatibility issue using IE11, Angular 10, and D3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in favor of Michael's opinion. The issue is introduced by version 3.6.0 due to support of `y` flag. Besides Michael's solution, you can also refer to this workaround:

You can replace the following line in your **polyfills.ts**:

```
import 'core-js';
```

to

```
import 'core-js/stable/array';
import 'core-js/stable/date';
import 'core-js/stable/function';
import 'core-js/stable/map';
import 'core-js/stable/math';
import 'core-js/stable/number';
import 'core-js/stable/object';
import 'core-js/stable/parse-float';
import 'core-js/stable/parse-int';
// import 'core-js/stable/regexp';
import 'core-js/stable/set';
// import 'core-js/stable/string';
import 'core-js/stable/symbol';
import 'core-js/stable/weak-map';
```

Note that the imports regexp and string are commented. So when your application needs to do a split, it's using the native function of the browser instead of the split function in core-js.

Comment: **Thanks a million** - excellent tip till the proper patch is implemented in core-js 3.6.5+

Answer (score 2):

I think you are hitting [issue #751](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/751)

This occurs from core-js 3.6.0, when two different versions of the polyfill are loaded. Currently the issue is still open, so solutions at the moment would be to make sure no two versions are loaded, or downgrade to <3.6.0.

The following may help identify the different versions of *core-js* in your dependency tree:

```
npm list | grep core-js
```

Comment: I definitely have a problem with 3.65 and 3.64 core-js simultaneously being present in my npm list for core-js dependencies.  This identifies the source of the problem, and Yu Zhou's comment provides the means to temporarily workaround the issue. **Many thanks** for letting me know about this issue bug in core-js.